# calculate difference between dates with conditional in a computed field drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, datediff, drupal-computed-field

I have a computed field (field:length_of_stay) for calculate the difference between a starting date (field:date_of_admission) and the current date for content type "Patient".
My Computed Code (PHP) in field settings is:

```
`$field_date_of_admission = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 
'field_date_of_admission'));
$start_date = new DateObject($field_date_of_admission['value'], '');
$current_date = new DateObject('now', '', 'm/d/Y');
$length_of_stay = $start_date->difference($current_date, 'days');
$entity_field[0]['value'] =  $length_of_stay;
}`
```

Display code is:

```
`$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];`
```

It works although it starts from 0 date.

My problem is that when I want to deactivate a patient the computed field continues to calculate the difference which seems wrong for my application purposes. (Content type Patient has also field:active with acceptable values Yes or No).

Is it possible to use an if statement or something? I don't know PHP actually.
Can someone provide some guidance here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the code with following code and need to double check with `field_active` field machine name goes here.

```
$field_date_of_admission = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_date_of_admission'));
$active = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_active'));
if ($active) {
    $start_date = new DateObject($field_date_of_admission['value'], '');
    $current_date = new DateObject('now', '', 'm/d/Y');
    $length_of_stay = $start_date->difference($current_date, 'days');
    $entity_field[0]['value'] = $length_of_stay;
} else {
    $entity_field[0]['value'] = 0;
}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!Even though I don't want inactive patients to have 0 days in length of stay field, I tried your code, but it doesn't seem to work completely.I mean it calculates correctly but when I deactivate patient it doesn't turn to zero.So, I think I'm missing something here...Could you please clarify what you mean by double checking field_active?

Comment: You need to debug the $active and modify conditions according to it.

Comment: I tried if ($active == 'true'), if ($active == 1) and I kept the rest of the code as it is but no luck so far.

Comment: Put code above​ if condition `drupal_set_message($active);` and check what value comming and then put Condition according to it.

Comment: `drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($active).'<pre>')` 
 
Put code above​ if condition then you get what is coming in array.

Comment: thanks, I checked the value it's 1 for active patient or 0 for inactive. When I use your code all the nodes(I have 5 nodes for testing) give 0 days in all cases.If I remove the else part it calculates days but misses two days in 4 nodes (the 5th stays 0).I'm confused..  i don't have the background in informatics, I'm a nurse...    here's the if part: if ($active == '1')

Answer (score 0):

A friend gave me this code and works for me, so here it is for anyone who may need something similar. It calculates the length of stay, both for active or inactive patients.
Content type: "Patient". Fields: field_length_of_stay (computed field), field_date_of_admission (date), field_date_of_discharge (date), field_active (Boolean 1/Yes,0/No).

```
$field_date_of_admission = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_date_of_admission'));
$field_active = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_active');
$field_date_of_discharge = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_date_of_discharge'));

 if ($field_active[0]['value'] == '1') {
  $ad_date = new DateObject($field_date_of_admission['value'], '');
  $current_date = new DateObject('now', '', 'm/d/Y');
  $los = $ad_date->difference($current_date, 'days');
  $entity_field[0]['value'] =  $los;
} else {
  $ad_date = new DateObject($field_date_of_admission['value'], '');
  $dis_date = new DateObject($field_date_of_discharge['value'], '');
  $los = $ad_date->difference($dis_date, 'days');
  $entity_field[0]['value'] =  $los;
}
```